# How to split dataframe into multiple dataframes based on header rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

I need to split a dataframe into 3 unique dataframes based on a header-row reoccuring in the dataframe.

My dataframe looks like:

```
        0         1             2     ....   14
0   Alert     Type      Response           Cost
1     w1        x1            y1            z1
2     w2        x2            y2            z3
.      .         .             .             .
.      .         .             .             .
144 Alert     Type      Response           Cost
145   a1        b1            c1             d1
146   a2        b2            c2             d2
```

I was trying to get the index numbers containing the word "Alert" with loc to slice the dataframe into the sub dataframes.

```
indexes = df.index[df.loc[df[0] == "Alert"]].tolist()
```

But this returns:

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Any hint on that error or is there even a way I don't see (e.g. smth like group by?)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `np.split`

```
dfs = np.split(df, np.flatnonzero(df[0] == 'Alert')[1:])
```

#### Explanation

- Find where `df[0]` is equal to `'Alert'`

  ```
  np.flatnonzero(df[0] == 'Alert')
  ```
- Ignore the first one because we don't need an empty list element

  ```
  np.flatnonzero(df[0] == 'Alert')[1:]
  ```
- Use `np.split` to get the list

  ```
  np.split(df, np.flatnonzero(df[0] == 'Alert')[1:])
  ```

---

#### show results

```
print(*dfs, sep='\n\n')

      0     1         2     14
0  Alert  Type  Response  Cost
1     w1    x1        y1    z1
2     w2    x2        y2    z3

        0     1         2     14
144  Alert  Type  Response  Cost
145     a1    b1        c1    d1
146     a2    b2        c2    d2
```

Answer (score 2):

@piRSquared answer works great, so let me just explain you error.

This is how you can get the indexes where the first element is `Alert`:

```
indexes = list(df.loc[df['0'] == "Alert"].index)
```

Your error arises from the fact that `df.index` is a [pandas.RangeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html) object, so it cannot be further indexed.

Then you can split your dataframe using a list comprehension like this:

```
listdf = [df.iloc[i:j] for i, j in zip(indexes, indexes[1:] + [len(df)])]
```

Comment: Sometimes we forget to do this.  Very useful.